# Wait for a logo to load, fade in the logo, fade out after delay then fade in rest of site

Tags: jquery, load

I am new to jquery and having trouble with the following code. I want to wait for my logo to load then fade it in. Hold it on the screen for a period, fade it out then fade in the rest of the site. I need to wait for the logo to load because my first jquery file would fade in the logo before it had completed loading. My jquery is as follows:

```
$("#logo").bind("load", function () {
    $(this).fadeIn(1500, function() { 
        $(this).delay(4500).fadeOut(1500, function() {

        $(".headerwrapperhome")
            .css({ opacity:0, visibility:"visible" })
            .animate({ opacity:1 }, "slow");

        $("#firstwrapper")
            .css({ opacity:0, visibility:"visible" })
            .animate({ opacity:1 }, "slow"); 

        });
    });
});
```

At the moment all I am seeing is a black screen (background colour for the site)

As I said I am new to jquery so its probably something simple to fix.

Thanks for helping

Comment: is `$("#logo")` an `<img>`?  maybe make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You would need to bind the load event before the element loads, which becomes a problem with cached images because said event will happen immediately and synchronously. You'll need to use a preloading technique.

Comment: Yes it is. It is a png file loaded in with css as a background image into the div logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool thing about jQuery is it lets you chain functions together, and some functions (luckily in your case "FadeIn/Out" come with a callback function)!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // simplest solution    
    $('img').hide(0).delay(3000).fadeIn(333, function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(333, function () {
            $('#content').fadeIn(333);
        });
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/JRtGS/

Comment: I tried something similar to this but it did not work well because the content that comes after the logo is a mosaic of small images. I want those to continue to load while the logo is fading in, holding, and fading out so that by the time the logo has faded out the visitor see the mosaic already loaded in

Comment: thanks for accepting - i figured it would be a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the code provided by whitebOx and this seemed to provide a suitable solution. A melting pot of my code and his:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#logo').hide(0).delay(3000).fadeIn(1500, function () {
        $(this).delay(4000).fadeOut (1500, function () {
            $(".headerwrapperhome, #firstwrapper")
  .css({ opacity:0, visibility:"visible" })
  .animate({ opacity:1 }, "slow");
        });
    });
});
```